# PHP nothing gets in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem, nothing enters the database.  I checked everything.  No errors.

```
    <?
<?php

try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO hackmodz(id, user, password, hwid, time, till, banned) VALUES(:id, :user, :password, :hwid, :time, :till, :banned');
$req->execute(array(
    ':id' => $_GET['id'],
    ':user' => '',
    ':password' => $_GET['pass'],
    ':hwid' => $_GET['hwid'],
    ':time' => '',
    ':till' => '',
    ':banned' => '' 
));

echo 'Le jeu a bien ete ajoute !';

?>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\msx\index.php on line 21
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\msx\index.php on line 21

Comment: You should tell PDO to throw exceptions: `$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`. Do you get any messages now?

Comment: How do you know there are no errors?  I don't see you checking for errors.

Comment: Looks like there's a missing parenthesis at the end of the query: `:banned');` should be `:banned)');`.

Comment: `<?
<?php` what's up with that? Remove the `<?`

Comment: Look I added the errors

Comment: Ok, who wants to close this puppy?

Comment: Thanks @Rocket Hazmat for hipping me to [colon-less binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#Hcom71929).

Comment: @showdev: I could've also sworn there was a bug report about that somewhere, but I can't find it.  I'm not sure if it's a behavior that's supposed to be there or a bug, but it seems to work.

Comment: What is your quesiton? How is it different and how is it related to your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/23250649/367456)?

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors.

The two opening `<?` and `<?php` tags, remove `<?`

Plus, the quote in `:banned'` and a missing `)` however I replaced those with double quotes.

```
<?php

try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
            die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
$req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO hackmodz(id, user, password, hwid, time, till, banned) VALUES(:id, :user, :password, :hwid, :time, :till, :banned)");
$req->execute(array(
    ':id' => $_GET['id'],
    ':user' => '',
    ':password' => $_GET['pass'],
    ':hwid' => $_GET['hwid'],
    ':time' => '',
    ':till' => '',
    ':banned' => '' 
));

echo 'Le jeu a bien ete ajoute !';

?>
```

Plus, I quote Jeroen: *"You should tell PDO to throw exceptions: `$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`"*